# Does virtualenv isolate python itself + python packages, or just python packages?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I just installed virtualenv onto my ubuntu 12.10 laptop.  Am I supposed to install python itself into this vritualenv as well as all future python packages into this virtualenv?

Or is python not included in virtualenv typically?

when I type in 'which python' at the bash command line, I get /usr/bin/python, and it's python 2.7.3.  Should I install, say python 2.7.5 inside virtualenv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualenv installs python, but it's installed in the bin directory of the virtualenv you created. Therefore you need to run it with `./bin/python`.

You can also "activate" the virtualenv by running

```
source bin/activate
```

Which will put the virtualenvs bin directory first in the path (and do some other trickery I think) which will make the virtualenvs Python the default Python, so you can start it with just `python`. But this is not necessary.